# Java: Assign a variable within lambda

Tags: java, regex, variables, lambda, java-8

I cannot do this in Java:

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
String result;
optStr.ifPresent(s -> result = s);
```

The doc says that the variables used in lambdas must be effectively final.
Then how to extract and store something from a lambda into a variable nicely?

Actually the real use case is more complex.
I want to apply several regular expressions to a string one after another with `matcher.replaceAll`. I'm doing this in a forEach lambda and wanted to store intermediate results somewhere.

Comment: What is your whole use-case? What do you want to do with `result`?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `orElse` / `orElseGet`

Comment: Actually the use case is more complex. The lambda expression is larger and I want to assign certain variables inside the lambda

Comment: For this particular example, there are obvious alternatives that don't involve leaning on the mutation crutch.  Which is also almost certainly true of the "more complex" examples you've got in mind (but haven't shared.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz the real use case is not a secret. See edited question.

Comment: So you have a stream of regular expressions? And where does the replacement come from?

Answer (score 9):

The answer is simple: you can't (directly) do that.

A *very ugly* hack would be to mutate an external object instead of assigning to a variable:

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
optStr.ifPresent(s -> sb.append(s));
String result = sb.toString();
```

This works because `sb` is [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) here

But I want to emphasize the point that this is probably not what you really want to do.

- If you want to have a default value, use `optStr.orElse` or `optStr.orElseGet` instead.
- If you want to map the result only if it is present, use `optStr.map`

Since you did not provide your whole use-case, these are just guesses but the key point is that I really do not recommend the above snippet of code: it goes against the concept of functional programming (by mutating an object).

Comment: The use cases are many. For example if you want to increase an outside integer counter in a forEach lambda you can not do that. Or you just want to store some intermediate results from a cyclic calculation. You have to enclose them in dummy objects.

Comment: @George Because "increase an outside integer counter in a forEach" sounds a lot like filtering and then counting, which would be a functional way of doing it. Having said that, you could also create your own `MutableInteger` and increment that object instead. You can't assign but you can mutate.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, similar to what Tunaki has written, is to use a single-cell table:

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
String[] temp = new String[1];
optStr.ifPresent(s -> temp[0] = s);
String result = temp[0];
```

The table object is final, what changes is its content.

Edit: A word of warning though - before using this *hacky solution* check out the other answers to OP's question, pointing out why it's a bad idea to use this workaround and consider if it's really worth it!

Comment: I totally agree with Tunaki, and the fact that using this workaround is a bad idea, I just pointed out that you can 'hack' it other way.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I'll edit it pointing to Tunaki's warnings.

Answer (score 4):

If the code

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
String result;
optStr.ifPresent(s -> result = s);
```

was legal, it still was useless, as the variable `result` is not [*definitely assigned*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html) after the invocation of `ifPresent`. Java does not allow reading local variables which are only conditionally initialized. So you would need an alternative value for `result` for the case of an empty `Optional`, e.g.:

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
String result=null;// or any other default value
optStr.ifPresent(s -> result = s);
```

But then, if you have defined such a default/fall-back value, you can use the method intended for this purpose:

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
String result=optStr.orElse(null /* or any other default value */);
```

When you say, you have to initialize more than one variable, it doesn’t change the fact that these variables need to be initialized in either case. Also, there is no benefit in performing the initialization of dependent variables inside a lambda expression passed to the `Optional` as, after all, the `Optional` carries only a single value. Everything dependent on that value can get determined *after* getting that value, independently of the `Optional`:

```
Optional<String> optStr = Optional.of("foo");
Type1 variable1;
Type2 variable2;
Type3 variable3;
if(optStr.isPresent()) {
    String s=optStr.get();
    // determine and assign variable1, variable2, variable3 based on s
} else {
    // assign defaults/fall-backs to variable1, variable2, variable3
}
```

Note that even if your variables are already pre-initialized and you want to mutate them, using `if(optional.isPresent()) /* local modifications */` is the simplest way to do it. There’s nothing that works better when you replace this idiom with a lambda expression.

Comment: I gave the Optional only for simple illustration. In fact the lambda is arbitrary. Could be a forEach or some custom implementation.

Comment: @George: the point doesn’t change. You can’t mutate a local variable using lambda expressions. The correct way to do it will depend on each use case, but we can only answer the question you are actually asking, not the one in your mind.

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual use case.

Comment: Well, nothing really important has changed. In your original question, you wanted to replace an `if` statement by lambda expression, now you’re saying that you want to replace a `for` loop with a lambda expression. The answer still holds. Converting imperative code to use lambda expressions is not an improvement in any way.

Comment: very useless answer as it appeared on my search for "assigning value of a loca variable inside lambda in java".

Comment: @saferJo it’s an answer to the question you see at the top of this page. It wasn’t possible for me to influence what will appear in someone's search two and a half year later.

Comment: its never late to improve @Holger :)

Comment: @saferJo it’s not an improvement to change an answer to address an entirely different question. Continue searching for *matching* questions or open a new one, if you don’t find an existing one. But stop insisting on me to change this answer to address a question you have never asked. I never claimed that this answer was addressing your unasked question.

Comment: what do you mean by "stop insisting" I just mentioned it once you can say that if someone is repeating a thing to you...

Comment: never mind do whatever you want with your question of course. I just didn't find what I was send for here.

Comment: @saferJo you are repeatedly insisting that there was something wrong or improvable in this answer, even in a very rude manner (calling this answer “very useless”) in your first comment. Since you are still saying something about “improve”, despite the explanation that this post never was intended to read your mind and answer your unasked question, the word “insisting” is appropriate. It seems you have a very odd thinking about how this site works. This is not “my question”. This is the question of a user named “George” and it has four answers, probably none of them addressing your question.

Comment: you behave like it is your question, so I did the typo... :D just kidding man, don't take it with your heart.

Answer (score 2):

As per Java Specification, lambda gets the variable values as final from the surrounding context as the lambda is passed to that context at runtime.

The designer of the piece of code which accepts that lambda expression(or Functional Interface) accepts that interface instance\lambda with the faith that its values will not be altered. To strictly make the lambda faithful in this way Java language specification has kept this condition of accessing local context variables as final.

In short, a lambda is NOT supposed to change the state of the context in which it is invoked.

You can use an array to capture values, but still it is not advisable and hopefully java will detect and show warnings for such code in future revisions.