# Assigning local variables inside a lambda expression

Tags: java, string, lambda, option-type

I'm trying to learn and understand the use of lambda expressions in Java.

I have written a function within a class that returns a boolean result based on an `Optional` value using a lambda expression.

```
private boolean isNullOrEmpty(Optional<String> value) {
  boolean result;
  value.ifPresent(v -> result = isEmptyOrWhitespace(v));

  return result;
}
```

`isEmptyOrWhitespace` is a simple function I've defined elsewhere to check if a string is null or has only whitespace:

```
private boolean isEmptyOrWhitespace(String value) {
    return value == null || value.trim().isEmpty();
```

The issue is, I cannot compile this because the compiler says

```
variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final
```

For the `result` variable.  I have seen [Java: Assign a variable within lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518589/java-assign-a-variable-within-lambda) with a similar problem but there the problem involved String and the solution was to set it to null beforehand.

I feel I'm close. How can I fix this?

Comment: What should the code return if the `Optional` is empty?

Comment: @daniu sorry for the delay. It should return true.

Comment: Most of the times if you call `Optional.get` or `isPresent`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @lexicore I can sort of relate, it's like bad-practices 101 in python where you should never use global variables or pollute namespaces with dynamic variables. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A - Rewrite the code:

```
private boolean isNullOrEmpty(Optional<String> value) {
    return value.map(MyClass::isEmptyOrWhitespace).orElse(false);
}
```

Option B - Circumvent the "effectively final" restriction:

```
private boolean isNullOrEmpty(Optional<String> value) {
    boolean[] result = {false};
    value.ifPresent(v -> result[0] = isEmptyOrWhitespace(v));
    return result[0];
}
```

The *reference to the array* is final, its contents need not be.

Comment: Map sounds like the most sensible approach (certainly not hacky like B). This was very helpful, I'll test it out once I get home. So I've gathered that using lambda is impossible based on the comments here. Any way to figure out when what construct is applicable to which situation?

Comment: One more thing. Will this still work if Optional is empty? I'm guessing yes, that's what the orElse() bit is for? Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm not used to these Java 8 expressions.

Comment: @coldspeed yes, [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) returns the given value if the optional is empty, otherwise the optional's value.

Comment: @Bohemian I am sorry, but I'm downvoting this for the *Circumvent the "effectively final" restriction* part. I think this is a horrible advice.

Comment: Just tested this, and Option A is perfect. I also didn't know about the `::` syntax. Neat stuff, thanks!

Comment: @lexi why is it horrible advice exactly? The code works and is rock solid. What is the precise reason it’s “horrible”?

Comment: @Bohemian It mixes "side effects programming" with functional style.

Comment: @lexi it’s a local variable and a local lambda. It’s a bit severe to wave the design pattern flag at it. There’s nothing unexpected or dangerous going on. It’s no worse than something like `.forEach(myList::add)`, which is common enough and doesn’t raise eyebrows yet is still a mutating action.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `result` is not *effectively final* as there are more than one assignments to it.

You can use `Optional.map`

```
private boolean isNullOrEmpty(Optional<String> value) {
  return value.map(v -> isEmptyOrWhitespace(v)) //Or can use a Method reference as mentioned by Bohemian@
        .orElse(false);
}
```

Comment: Would be even better with a method reference.

Comment: @lexicore Yes. I have mentioned it in comments.

Comment: Why not in your answer? Most people won't read all the comments in the question.

Comment: @lexicore I would prefer to redirect to an already written answer by someone else since it already exists. I would change/edit the answer only if it makes a real difference (w.r.t to performance/functionality).

Comment: Well, it's your decision, of course. My approach is normally to ask "what is the best for the future readers?"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` with `isPresent`:

```
value.filter(x-> isEmptyOrWhitespace(x)).isPresent()
```